# How can I check if a number have the same digits? (in a func)

Tags: c++, function

I want to build a function in c++ that's running on [10] char array, so I want to check if I have same digits at the current place at the array.

For example:

110, 292 and so on have the same and it's invalid.

123, 345678, 98732, 3, 125 are valid.

Comment: Show some code. We can't fix what we can't see. Otherwise, it's not clear what help you need.

Comment: In addition to posting some code, a little bit more explanation of the reasoning you are using would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by `[10] char array`

If you want to see if a number has any digit in base 10 that appears twice you can use `std::bitset` or similar then use `x % 10` to get a digit and `x /= 10` until x becomes 0.

```
bool hasRepeatedDigit( unsigned int num, unsigned int base )
{
    std::vector< char > cache( base ); // avoiding vector<bool>

    while( num )
    {
       unsigned int digit = num % base;
       if( cache[ base ] )
          return true;

       cache[ base ] = 'T'; // just mark it
       num /= base;
    }

    return false;
}
```

This is generic and assumes you have a number as a number, not as a string. If it's just a string it would be implemented differently.

Comment: sorry i mean a size 10 char array. what do u check in "cache[ base ]" ?

Comment: I am avoiding using vector<bool> so I am using vector<char> instead. There is no relevance to the 'T' other than it not being a 0 char. The solution is generic to any base so you can look for repeating digits in hexadecimal or any other base. Of course in base 2 every number has repeating digits except 0, 1, and 10 (2)

Answer (score 1):

may be done in several ways, but one that comes fast is to setup an array to check if a digits has already been found, like:

```
char found[10];
memset(found,0x00,10);

char* c = yourbuffer;
while (c) {
    int digit = c - '0';
    if (!found[digit]) found[digit] = 1;
    else /* NOT UNIQUE, BREAK AND SET ERROR ACCORDING */
    c++;
}
```

Comment: also, I just notice that you told is a 10 chars array , so if the array isn't null terminated, you just need to change the while with a for(int n = 0; n < 10; n++) loop

Comment: This is tagged C++, so maybe a more c++ approach would be reasonable?

Comment: well, i don't find that a string iterator and a std::set fits well into the user request... also I personally consider it less efficient.

Comment: You could for example use an array of `bool` and zero-initialize it (`bool found[10] = {};`)

Answer (score 0):

Possible implementation :

```
bool hasDupDigits(char const *array, std::size_t size) {
    // If there are more than ten digits, there ought to be duplicates.
    if(size > 10)
        return true;

    // Using ten bits to store whether we already encountered a digit
    unsigned short storage = 0, mask;

    // Will stop on a null-terminator or after size chars.
    for(; size && *array; ++array, --size) {
        // Find which bit we are to consider
        mask = ((short)1) << (*array) - '0';
        // Return if we already set that bit
        if(storage & mask)
            return true;
        // Set the bit
        storage |= mask;
    }

    // No duplicate encountered
    return false;
}
```